# amazing result of date format in php

Tags: php, date

I am trying to change the date `13 December, 2016` using `date('Y-m-d',strtotime('13 December, 2016'))` and it gives me the result of `2017-12-13`, what i am missing here

Comment: You need to replace that `comma` from your date string and all will work fine

Comment: Y-m-d.. use M for Dec

Comment: thanks @NarendrasinghSisodia real credit for solving this problem goes to you, thanks for your quick comment

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that comma within the `date` strings create an issue while using the `strtotime` function you can replace it with `str_replace` or instead you can simply use `DateTime::createFromFormat` method so no need of using extra function like as

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F, Y','13 December, 2016');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

or simply `date_create_from_format`

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d F, Y','13 December, 2016');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('13 December 2016'));
```

You need to remove your comma.

This will give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$date = '13 December 2016';
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
```

The `m` formats the month to its numerical representation there.

Mistake: You don't have to put coma there.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    $time = strtotime('10/21/2016');
$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);
echo $newformat;
```